# Distinguish Google Play Sandbox purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

Is there any way to distinguish in-app purchase made through Google Play Sandbox  vs real purchase? Whether from application side or using some API, like this one: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1_1/inapppurchases/get

Comment: Do you want to do it programmatically ?

Comment: Yes, to filter them from real ones on my server.

Comment: Hey did you managed to solve this? I have the same issue

Comment: unfortunately, no solution so far

Comment: has this been resolved yet, can you distinguish a transaction in the Sandbox and one in Production?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no API for that.

The only way that I see is to modify the code before you move to production (from draft). If it is acceptable for you then here is it:

Use the developerPayload to indicate whether the application is in production or not. Whatever you had in your developerPayload before could be changed this way (JSON or anything else to separate the two data), so you won't loose anything.

```
{
   "data": "your_old_developer_payload"
   "isProduction": "false"
}
```

This is just a workaround. You have to decide weather you face the additional work when you move from draft to production.

Comment: Hi, developer payload could work for me, but I guess, the app is not able to detect whether sandbox account is used or not. The thing is that I can use sandbox accouunt even on published app and I want detect that (even using payload, it will be OK).

Comment: Well, can you use sandbox account on a production App? Will the purchases free? I did not know that, in that situation you can not distinguish.

Comment: Yeah, I can use sandbox account on production app (account is added as a test account).